# how to install SmallFry MVC Framework under Xampp

Tags: php

How to install and use SmallFry framework.

1. I downloaded it from https://github.com/maniator/SmallFry
2. Extracted it under htdocs and placed all content in folder: smallfry (C:\xampp\htdocs\smallfry).
3. Set Doc root to define('DOCROOT', 'C:/xampp/htdocs'); in Autoloader.php.
4. Changed db info to following settings---

> ```
> $CONFIG->set('DB_INFO', array(
>     'host' => 'localhost',
>     'login' => 'root',
>     'password' => '',
>     'database' => 'smallfry',
> ));
> ```

Still getting the following error --

[image: Error]

let me know what else need to be change as i m very new to this framework.

Comment: Seems like you are using PHP4 instead of required PHP5 (due to first two errors).

Comment: @webbandit im using PHP 5.3.8

Comment: Oh, I mean you use framework built for PHP4. Sorry for delusion )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the framework is a bit out-dated, as assigning the return vlaue of new by reference is indeed deprecated. You should look for `$x =& new Obj;` calls and remove the `&`.

The Fatal error should be fixed after fixing the other issues. According to the documentation, that method should exist.

Comment: i found this framework today on Stack site advertisement sidebar ..so thought its a new one ...seems useless ..and let me know if im wrong :)

Answer (score 1):

Fatal error occurs due to first two errors.

Because of Deprecated warnings `Config` class wasn't loaded correctly.